# Extend Screens Showing "Input Not Supported"

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have an old hp monitor (With VGA input) that I've connected to my dell laptop through an HDMI-to-VGA adapter. In my display settings, I have "Extend these screens" selected. But the old hp monitor is showing "Input Not Supported".

Comment: Have you checked, which screen resolutions the HP monitor can display, and made sure, you chose one of those in the display settings? With many HDMI/VGA adapters this information can ot be automatically retrieved by the OS.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=hp+w17e+monitor%27s+supported+resolutions&oq=hp+w17e+monitor%27s+supported+resolutions&aqs=chrome..69i57.9347j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: 1440*900 but in this resolution i can't even duplicate. i have changed to 1280*sth and that too only duplicates. it doesn't extend. i have tried with all possible resolutions as well. it didn't help.

Comment: That's fine - but did you chose 1440x900@75 as the resolution for this monitor in the display settings?

Comment: Most likely you chose 1280x1024, which can't be displayed on a 1440x900 monitor.